# Как поменять цвет текста в выпадающем списке Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Такая ситуация: я использую `Spinner` в активити и все отлично работает, цвет текста в выпадающем списке черный и правильно отображается. Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, когда я использую ту же имплементацию, но в кастомном `Dialog`, то выпадающий список выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, что, когда я открываю `Spinner` в `Dialog`, то он в выпадающем списке берет стиль `Dialog`-а

Как сделать так, чтобы текст в выпадающем списке на втором изображении был таким же, как и на первом?

```
private void setManagerListSpinnerAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter<ManagerItem> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(ElectraHeverApplication.getInstance(),
                    R.layout.custom_spinner_view, android.R.id.text1, managerList);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_drop_down);

    spManagerList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

XML R.layout.custom_spinner_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
style="@style/FrameTextView"
>

<TextView
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:singleLine="true"
  style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
  />

<ImageButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_margin="8dp"
  android:background="@drawable/down_arrow_black"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML R.layout.custom_drop_down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
      style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Стиль @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle

```
<style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/disabled_text_background</item>
<item name="android:gravity">right</item>
<item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Такая имплементация с этими файлами работает у меня в активити и все хорошо, но эта же имплементация в `Dialog` уже выглядит иначе...

Если что-то забыл, то спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге я нашел в чем было дело

После того как был создан `ArrayAdapter` в него нужно установить `dropDownView` вот так

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_drop_down);
```

и в разметке этого `custom_drop_down` было вот так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
      style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:singleLine="true"/>
```

а нужно было вот так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
      style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:singleLine="true"/>
```

разница в строке `style`

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

При создании адаптера передавайте эту, свою разметку. Также попробуйте поставить черный текст.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638593/change-holo-spinner-text-colour если поможет изменю ответ

Comment: Я не совсем уверен, что в этом проблема... Я добавил в вопрос файлы разметки. Такая имплементация с этими файлами работает у меня в активити и все хорошо, но эта же имплементация, но в `Dialog` уже выглядит иначе...